# Python: Cherry Py return ZIP File. How to return zip file in cherrypy as download

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, cherrypy

Here is my sample code:
The problem is it returns a downloadable zip file but the file is corrupted/ has error. I checked the file by manually opening it in a folder and it works. I think the problem here is passing the zip file from backend to cherrypy. Or how do I convert the zip file into a file type?

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "'Content-Type', 'application/zip'"
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment; filename=' + 
    name.format(fname=name))
export_file = str(response["message_data"]["file"])

return export_file
```

Creating ZIP File

```
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(full_directory + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(full_directory + '/'):
    for file in files:
        zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file), arcname=file)
zipf.close()

file_upload = open(full_directory + '.zip', "r")
```

Passing ZIP File to CherryPy:

```
response_json["message_data"]["file"] = file_upload
response_json["message_data"]["name"] = file_name
```

Comment: Could you paste all code for your endpoint serving zip?

Comment: What do you mean sir? The way I create the zip or the way I pass the zip?

Comment: he means HTTP handler which is triggered whenever you get an incoming HTTP request

Comment: Anyway, you likely need to create it in-memory using `BytesIO` and then return that from the handler. There's a few similar questions on SO already answered.

Comment: I need to create it as file cause I upload it to s3 server